# How to recover from apt-get remove ubuntu-desktop^?

Tags: 14.04, apt, login

I was trying to convert ubuntu desktop to ubuntu server and did:

```
sudo apt-get purge ubuntu-dektop^
```

The system startted to remove packages and hanged at the following messages:

```
Removing network-manager (0.9.8.8-0ubuntu7.2) ...
```

After that I am unable to login to the system in anyway. If I login from local console I get textual login prompt but am unable to type any username.

Is it possible to reach system from now?